# Trying to update variable in do-catch block that will be returned: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, alamofire

I want to return `currData` which is from type `wData` (custom type). `currData` is declared at the beginning of the function and will be set in a `do-catch` block:

```
func getWData(stnID: Int) -> wData{
   var currData: wData?

   let parameters: Parameters = ["id": String(stnID), "accesstype": "w"]

   Alamofire.request("https://myurl.tld", parameters: parameters).response { response in
       print("Request: \(response.request)")
       print("Response: \(response.response)")
       print("Error: \(response.data)")

       if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
           print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

           let dArr = utf8Text.components(separatedBy: "~")
           do {
               try currData = wData(hash: Int(dArr[0])!, stnName: String(dArr[1])!)
           } catch {
               print("error creating wData Object: \(error)")
           }

       }
   }   

   return currData!
}
```

But when I try to return the `currData` object I get the following error message:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My `wData` class looks like this:

```
class wData{
     var hash: Int
     var stnName: String

     init(hash: Int, stnName: String) {
         self.hash     = hash
         self.stnName  = stnName
     }
}
```

I thought that I could create a static variable in my class:

```
class wData{

     static var currDObj: wData?
     var hash: Int
     var stnName: String

     init(hash: Int, stnName: String) {
         self.hash     = hash
         self.stnName  = stnName

         currDObj = self
     }
}
```

And then return the currDObj in my getWData function with:

```
return weatherData.currData!
```

But it still gives me an error. What point did I do wrong?

Comment: What is the value of dArr[0] and dArr[1]

Comment: You can't return a value from a function that makes an asynchronous call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line `try currData = wData(hash: Int(dArr[0])!, stnName: String(dArr[1])!)` will most likely not be evaluated before this line `return currData!` so currData is still nil. You need to use a closure with your function rather than returning the value.

Something like this: (also improved nil safety)

```
func getWData(stnID: Int, completion: (wData?) -> ()) {

    let parameters: Parameters = ["id": String(stnID), "accesstype": "w"]

    Alamofire.request("https://myurl.tld", parameters: parameters).response { response in
        print("Request: \(response.request)")
        print("Response: \(response.response)")
        print("Error: \(response.data)")

        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)")

            let dArr = utf8Text.components(separatedBy: "~")
            guard let hash = Int(dArr[0]), stnName = String(dArr[1]) else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }
            do {
                let currData: wData = try wData(hash: hash, stnName: stnName)
                completion(currData)

            } catch {
                print("error creating wData Object: \(error)")
                completion(nil)
            }

        }
        else {
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while I agree it will fail because of it being asynchronous, but doesn't it also fail *if* the try fails...leading to currData being nil and crashing?

Comment: @rmaddy I'm not the OP :). But I was referring to the original code from OP. Can include that in your reply

Comment: @Honey Then you should post your comment to the question, not this answer. I'll delete my comments after you delete yours and post it properly.

Comment: @rmaddy Apologies for the short memory I have. *Actually* I was referring to the answer's first line. He was saying the `try` will not be evaluated before the `return`. I was attempting to point /ask about another flaw and I thought he neglected including that in his explanation

Comment: Technically speaking, it's possible for the code in the closure to run before the containing function is finished, but yes that's another possible place it could break, which is why I fixed it in my answer. But it's almost guaranteed to crash at that return statement

Comment: In my function I need `completion: @escaping (wData?) -> ()` instead of `completion: (wData?) -> ()`.  When I try to call the function i use this code: `let currData:  wData` and call the function like this: `dataHandler().getWData(stnID: "someId", completion: currData)` but I get the following error: _Can not convert value of type wData to expected argument type '(wData?) -> ()'_ Which point did I do wrong with calling the function?

Comment: In the `do` section xCode give me a warning: _No calls to throwing functions occur within 'try' expression_. And in the `catch` section I get this warning: _'catch' block is unreachable because no errors are thrown in 'do' block_

Comment: Well if you don't know what a closure is... https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html